# How to Assert A Method in Mocked Object Has Been Called?

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I a learning python mock, and having problem to check if a method on a mocked object has been called.

The code I want to test is this:

```
def main(flags, directory_service):
  if flags.has_schema:
    directory_service.HasSchema(SCHEMA_NAME)
    sys.exit(1)
```

My test code is:

```
def testHaltsAfterCheckingSchema(self):
  mock_flags = self._CreateDefaultFlags()
  mock_flags.has_schema = True
  mock_directory_service = MagicMock()

  with self.assertRaises(SystemExit) as cm:
    key_distributor.main(mock_flags, mock_directory_service)
  self.assertTrue(mock_directory_service.HasSchema.assert_called_with(key_distributor.SCHEMA_NAME))
  self.assertEqual(cm.exception.code, 1)
```

And when I run it, I get this exception:

```
FAIL: testHaltsAfterCheckingSchema (test123.Test123)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test123.py", line 34, in testHaltsAfterCheckingSchema
    self.assertTrue(mock_directory_service.HasSchema.assert_called_with(key_distributor.SCHEMA_NAME))
AssertionError: None is not true
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`assert_called_with` does the assertion directly, and returns `None`. You do not need to use `TestCase.assertTrue()` here at all.

In other words, the following is enough:

```
mock_directory_service.HasSchema.assert_called_with(key_distributor.SCHEMA_NAME)
```

If this assertion fails (i.e. `directory_service.HasSchema()` was not called or called with different arguments) then that `assert_called_with` raises an [`AssertError` exception](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#AssertionError), which `TestCase` catches for you and records as a test failure:

```
>>> from unittest.mock import MagicMock
>>> mock_directory_service = MagicMock()
>>> mock_directory_service.HasSchema('SCHEMA_NAME')
<MagicMock name='mock.HasSchema()' id='4562465232'>
>>> mock_directory_service.HasSchema.assert_called_with('SCHEMA_NAME')
>>> mock_directory_service.HasSchema.assert_called_with('foobar')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/mj/Development/Library/buildout.python/parts/opt/lib/python3.4/unittest/mock.py", line 771, in assert_called_with
    raise AssertionError(_error_message()) from cause
AssertionError: Expected call: HasSchema('foobar')
Actual call: HasSchema('SCHEMA_NAME')
```